# How to remove indentation for a line in yasnippet for python-mode?

Tags: emacs, yasnippet

I would like to close my if statements with a comment indicating the condition checked in the if statement. I am using yasnippet with emacs and the snippet I use is this:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: if
# key: if
# group : control structure
# --
if ${1:cond}:
    $0
# endif $1
```

My problem is that the final **# endif** comment gets aligned with **$0**. Is there a way to make it align with the if statement?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The value of `yas-indent-line` controls this behavior. Try adding

```
# expand-env: ((yas-indent-line 'fixed))
```

to the header.